# Calculating gyroscope data from accelerometer and attitude data

Tags: signal-analysis, transform, preprocessing, conversion

I am currently collecting accelerometer and attitude data using smartphone sensors. Data is collected at 100Hz over 2.5 seconds. Of which there are 250 accelerometer points and 250 points representing the attitude of the device. I am looking to convert the attitude/accelerometer data to gyroscope Data. For example, 1 of the 250 segments look like;

For example,

**Accelerometer**

- AccX = 0.08458628
- AccY = -0.0586758144
- AccZ = 0.273877382

**Attitude**

- Pitch = 0.111681767
- Roll = -0.8779668
- Yaw = 1.91596484

How can I calculate the corrected gyroscope data from this data?

Comment: Are you trying to reconstruct angular velocity, or do you have gyro data as well that you are trying to filter? Perhaps this might be relevant: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/12589/correct-filter-to-find-angular-velocity-from-a-rotating-accelerometer

Comment: I am trying to calculate the angular velocity but we have the angle itself pitch roll and yaw. How would you calculate the angular velocity from these angles and accelerometer data?